# Coalesce between two tables when data is missing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Friends, I have query which looks up data from an address table based on the availability of a a billing address id within a credit cards table. The problem is that for many records in the credit cards table, the billing address id is a default value of  all zeroes. What I would like to do is when the billing address id is all zeroes, perform my inner join against another default address table. I believe the solution is in using Coalesce. Below is the query. Any help would be appreciated.

```
select top 1
       u_address_id,
       u_address_name,
       ads.u_first_name,
       ads.u_last_name,
       ads.u_address_line1,
       ads.u_address_line2,
       u_city,
       u_region_code,
       u_postal_code,
       u_country_code,
       ads.u_tel_number,
       ads.u_tel_extension,
       uo.u_email_address,
       uo.u_user_id,
       pm.PaymentMethodName,
       ccea.CreditCard,
       ccea.u_id
from       CreditCard_Export_All ccea
inner join CreditCards           cc   on ccea.creditcard       = cc.u_id
inner join Addresses             ads  on cc.u_billing_address  = ads.u_address_id
inner join UserObject            uo   on ccea.UserId           = uo.u_user_id
inner join PaymentMethod         pm   on cc.u_payment_group_id = pm.GroupId
where ccea.CreditCard = @ccId
  and ccea.u_id between @_startUId and @_endUId
  and uo.u_email_address is not null
  and uo.u_email_address like @site+'_%'
```

Comment: Perhaps you could simplify the problem, just to two or three tables and provide sample data and desired results.  That would make it easier to understand what needs to be done.

Comment: Coalesce will not help you, because it only lets you eliminate NULLs, not default values.  If you want to get the value that is not all zeroes, you can use a CASE statement.

Comment: The `other default address table` has only one row with u_address_id as all zeroes? It is not clear. Please publish some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes for you:

- The fact you need to say `top 1` to control the size of your results set is a code smell that suggests that you're not asking the right question in your SQL.
- Always qualify your column references with a table name alias. It makes your SQL much easier to read. And the next guy who has to understand it won't have to spend time trying to figure what column comes from what table.
- Always schema-qualify your table names (`dbo.some_table`). Unqualifed names have to be resolved on each call: unqualified object references must be resolved by

  - Probing the namespace of the current session's default schema
  - If not found, probing the `dbo` namespace.

  This slows down plan compilation, inhibits query plan caching and can cause creative, hard to diagnose errors if the current session's default schema own an object of the same name (`foo.some_table`) as the object you really want (`dbo.some_table`). Don't ask how I know this.
- Don't construct SQL like it looks like you're doing. It...

  - exposes you to SQL injection attacks
  - prevents caching of the execution plan and thus requires recompilation/rebinding of the plan on each execution. Note that this also takes out compilation locks on the dependent objects which can cause transient blocking and concurrency issues.
  - opens you up to...interesting errors when data doesn't take the form you think it does.

That aside, something like this ought to work for you:

```
select top 1
       address_id     = coalesce( ads.u_address_id    , soat.address_id       ) ,
       address_name   = coalesce( ads.u_address_name  , soat.address_name     ) ,
       first_name     = coalesce( ads.u_first_name    , soat.first_name       ) ,
       last_name      = coalesce( ads.u_last_name     , soat.last_name        ) ,
       addr_line_1    = coalesce( ads.u_address_line1 , soat.addr_line_1      ) ,
       addr_line_2    = coalesce( ads.u_address_line2 , soat.addr_line_2      ) ,
       city           = coalesce( ads.u_city          , soat.city             ) ,
       region_code    = coalesce( ads.u_region_code   , soat.region_code      ) ,
       postal_code    = coalesce( ads.u_postal_code   , soat.postal_code      ) ,
       country_code   = coalesce( ads.u_country_code  , soat.country_code     ) ,
       telephone      = coalesce( ads.u_tel_number    , soat.telephone_number ) ,
       telephone_ext  = coalesce( ads.u_tel_extension , soat.telephone_ext    ) ,
       email_address  = uo.u_email_address   ,
       user_id        = uo.u_user_id         ,
       payment_method = pm.PaymentMethodName ,
       credit_card    = ccea.CreditCard      ,
       credit_card_id = ccea.u_id
from      CreditCard_Export_All ccea
join      CreditCards           cc   on cc.u_id           = ccea.creditcard
join      UserObject            uo   on uo.u_user_id      = ccea.UserId
join      PaymentMethod         pm   on pm.GroupId        = cc.u_payment_group_id
left join Addresses             ads  on ads.u_address_id  = cc.u_billing_address
                                    and 0                != cc.u_billing_address
left join SomeOtherAddressTable soat on soat.address_id   = cc.some_other_address_id
                                    and 0                 = cc.u_billing_address
where ccea.CreditCard    =       @ccId
  and ccea.u_id          between @_startUId and @_endUId
  and uo.u_email_address is not  null
  and uo.u_email_address like    @site+'_%'
```

You might also look at using a UNION, something like this:

```
select address_id     = ads.u_address_id     ,
       address_name   = ads.u_address_name   ,
       first_name     = ads.u_first_name     ,
       last_name      = ads.u_last_name      ,
       addr_line_1    = ads.u_address_line1  ,
       addr_line_2    = ads.u_address_line2  ,
       city           = ads.u_city           ,
       region_code    = ads.u_region_code    ,
       postal_code    = ads.u_postal_code    ,
       country_code   = ads.u_country_code   ,
       telephone      = ads.u_tel_number     ,
       telephone_ext  = ads.u_tel_extension  ,
       email_address  = uo.u_email_address   ,
       user_id        = uo.u_user_id         ,
       payment_method = pm.PaymentMethodName ,
       credit_card    = ccea.CreditCard      ,
       credit_card_id = ccea.u_id
from CreditCard_Export_All ccea
join CreditCards           cc   on cc.u_id               = ccea.creditcard
                               and cc.u_billing_address != 0
join UserObject            uo   on uo.u_user_id          = ccea.UserId
join PaymentMethod         pm   on pm.GroupId            = cc.u_payment_group_id
join Addresses             ads  on ads.u_address_id      = cc.u_billing_address
where ccea.CreditCard    =       @ccId
  and ccea.u_id          between @_startUId and @_endUId
  and uo.u_email_address is not  null
  and uo.u_email_address like    @site+'_%'
UNION ALL
select address_id     = soat.address_id       ,
       address_name   = soat.address_name     ,
       first_name     = soat.first_name       ,
       last_name      = soat.last_name        ,
       addr_line_1    = soat.addr_line_1      ,
       addr_line_2    = soat.addr_line_2      ,
       city           = soat.city             ,
       region_code    = soat.region_code      ,
       postal_code    = soat.postal_code      ,
       country_code   = soat.country_code     ,
       telephone      = soat.telephone_number ,
       telephone_ext  = soat.telephone_ext    ,
       email_address  = uo.u_email_address    ,
       user_id        = uo.u_user_id          ,
       payment_method = pm.PaymentMethodName  ,
       credit_card    = ccea.CreditCard       ,
       credit_card_id = ccea.u_id
from CreditCard_Export_All ccea
join CreditCards           cc   on cc.u_id              = ccea.creditcard
                               and cc.u_billing_address = 0
join UserObject            uo   on uo.u_user_id         = ccea.UserId
join PaymentMethod         pm   on pm.GroupId           = cc.u_payment_group_id
left join SomeOtherAddressTable soat on soat.address_id = cc.some_other_address_id
                                    and 0               = cc.u_billing_address
where ccea.CreditCard    =       @ccId
  and ccea.u_id          between @_startUId and @_endUId
  and uo.u_email_address is not  null
  and uo.u_email_address like    @site+'_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution to this kind of problem, but it does use coalesce.

```
select top 1
u_address_id,
u_address_name,
Coalesce(ads.u_first_name,ads2.u_first_name) as 'u_first_name',
Coalesce(ads.u_last_name,ads2.u_last_name) as 'u_last_name',
Coalesce(ads.u_address_line1,ads2.u_address_line1) as 'u_address_line1',
Coalesce(ads.u_address_line2,ads2.u_address_line2) as 'u_address_line2',
u_city, u_region_code,
u_postal_code,
u_country_code,
Coalesce(ads.u_tel_number,ads2.u_tel_number) as 'u_tel_number',
Coalesce(ads.u_tel_extension,ads2.u_tel_extension) as 'u_tel_extension',
uo.u_email_address,
uo.u_user_id,
pm.PaymentMethodName,
ccea.CreditCard,
ccea.u_id

from CreditCard_Export_All ccea
inner join CreditCards cc on ccea.creditcard = cc.u_id
left outer join Addresses ads on cc.u_billing_address = ads.u_address_id and ads.u_address_id != '000000000'
left outer join [ANOTHER DEFAULT ADDRESS TABLE] ads2 on cc.u_billing_address = ads2.u_address_id
inner join UserObject uo on ccea.UserId = uo.u_user_id
inner join PaymentMethod pm on cc.u_payment_group_id = pm.GroupId

where ccea.CreditCard = '" + ccId + "'" +
"and ccea.u_id between '" + _startUId + "' and '" + _endUId + "' " +
"and uo.u_email_address is not null " +
"and uo.u_email_address like '" + site + "_%'";
```